# Can not insert my dropdownlist data in database with foreign key in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to pack my data in form with foreign key and send that to database.I collect data from database with controller and show in my view and when I complete the form can not send that to database and see the exception

my controller code is

```
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        testContext test = new testContext();
        List<SelectListItem> listselecteditem = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (Gender item in test.genders)
        {
            SelectListItem selectlist = new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = item.GenderType,
                Value = item.GenderID.ToString(),
            };
            listselecteditem.Add(selectlist);
        }
        ViewBag.Datalist = new SelectList(listselecteditem, "Value", "Text");
        return View();
    }
```

this controller get data from database and send to dropdownlist

and this controller save my data in database

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(Person p)
    {

        using (testContext test=new testContext())
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    test.persons.Add(p);
                    test.SaveChanges();
                    ViewBag.Message="Success";
                }
                catch (Exception ec)
                {

                    ViewBag.Message = ec.Message;
                }

            }
        }
        return View(p);
    }
```

this is my view

```
@model testmvc.Models.Person

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="pull-right col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading ">
                    <p>register</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "RegisterLogin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
                    {

                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                        <fieldset>
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                            @if (ViewBag.Messsage != null)
                            {
                                <div class="alert alert-success">
                                    <p>@ViewBag.Message</p>
                                </div>
                            }
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Fullname, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Full name" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @id = "last_name", @placeholder = "Username" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @id = "email", @placeholder = "Email address" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control input-sm floatlabel", @id = "first_name", @placeholder = "Password" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Comfirmpassword, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @id = "last_name", @placeholder = "confirmpassword" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @*<select>
                                        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.DataList)
                                        {
                                            <option>@item.Text</option>
                                        }
                                </select>*@
                                @Html.DropDownList("Datalist",String.Empty)
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Birthday, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @id = "password_confirmation", @placeholder = "Birthday yyyy/dd/mm" })
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary">
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my model code

```
public partial class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int personID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Fullname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [NotMapped]
    public String Comfirmpassword { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String EmailAddress { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public int GenderID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GenderID")]
    public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }
}

[Table("Gender")]
public partial class Gender
{
    [Key]
    public int GenderID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String GenderType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

this exception said there is not any viewdata key with "Datalist". how can I solve that and what is my code problem

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this exception is because inside `[HttpPost]` action you didn't populate the `ViewBag.Datalist` property, the way you did in your Get action. Since you redisplay the same view and this view requires this information in order to properly render the dropdown, you will need to populate it. To avoid repetition you could place this logic in a separate method:

```
private SelectList GetGenders()
{
    using (testContext test = new testContext())
    {
        List<SelectListItem> listselecteditem = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (Gender item in test.genders)
        {
            SelectListItem selectlist = new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = item.GenderType,
                Value = item.GenderID.ToString(),
            };
            listselecteditem.Add(selectlist);
        }
        return new SelectList(listselecteditem, "Value", "Text");
    }
}
```

which you are going to call in your 2 actions:

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    ViewBag.Datalist = GetGenders();
    return View();
}
```

and:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(Person p)
{
    using (testContext test = new testContext())
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                test.persons.Add(p);
                test.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.Message = "Success";
            }
            catch (Exception ec)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = ec.Message;
            }
        }
    }

    ViewBag.Datalist = GetGenders();
    return View(p);
}
```

Comment: thanks alot.I take a care and find out I can use linq code and deplicate it for all select,insert,delete and update.is this correct?I'm so new in asp.net MVC and can you say me what books I use to learn how to work with linq?